# Existence of Function from various Domains to various ranges.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Multiple correct options:

Which of the following is/are true?

(a) There is a surjective function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}.$

(b) There is a injective function $f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}.$

(c) There is a bijective function $f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}  \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}.$

(d) There is a bijective function $f:\left\{ 0,1 \right\} \times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}.$

I think (b) is only correct since bijective requires the same cardinality.

How should I do this one.

Comment: They're all true. All the sets here have the same cardinality.

Comment: @jgon How? Can you clear me?

Comment: What facts about functions on $\mathbb{N}$ do you know?

Comment: Also as a clue.  If you can show there is a bijective function $ f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $ you can use that to prove all the others.

Answer (score 0):

All the given alternatives are correct because if there is a bijective function between two sets then that function is surjective as well as injective.

Comment: It would be helpful to the person asking to show that the bijection exists.